# RSS feed for StackExchange sites in private beta are publicly viewable

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, feed, stackexchange-2.0, private-beta

At the time of writing, the Photography StackExchange proposal is in private beta, and I shouldn't be able to view it.

However, I can see the RSS feed at https://photo.stackexchange.com/feeds

Comment: Actually, I think you shouldn't be able to participate. I think this is by-design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

- [Observe a private beta in StackAuth](https://stackapps.com/questions/947/observe-a-private-beta-in-stackauth)
- [Site in closed beta but api working](https://stackapps.com/questions/956/site-in-closed-beta-but-api-working)

They allow read only access to the site because the point behind having a private beta is so that people who are committed to the site can begin to shape it in it's early days.

Being able to read the data cannot interfere with that process.

Check out [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/).  You can view the data on every one of the sites, private or not.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just came across this when doing some search engine research.

Comment: @George, no probs!  It's a good tool for viewing the private betas.